# is there any way to interpret pascal in Delphi applications

Tags: delphi, runtime, interpreter

i want my own pascal code to be executed it also have some uses files and other complex functions just like a Delphi code can i do this

Comment: Delphi for Win32 or Delphi for .net?

Comment: anything is OK it can even be a interpreter

Comment: @LachlanG - that link (question 226135 "scripting-library-for-delphi" ) has been removed "for moderation"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes:

- http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx

This component is used in the highly popular Inno Setup installer software.

Answer (score 5):

[Delphi Web Script](http://delphitools.info/tag/dws/) is now under active development again.
Previously it was good; now it is becoming great.
You can [download it on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/).

--jeroen

Answer (score 3):

Another option, which is useful if you want to support more than just Pascal syntax, would be [Fast-Script](http://www.fast-report.com/en/products/fast-script.html) by the makers of [Fast-Report](http://www.fast-report.com/en/products/report-generator-for-delphi-fastreport-4.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's also [paxCompiler](http://www.paxcompiler.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Depends how much pascal you want to interpret. [Pascal Script](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) will interpret most stuff but you can't declare classes in a script (You can however import them using script functions). You can't use "uses" clauses either.

If you want to do full on pascal support you're going to have to compile it. You could probably use the [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org) one providing your app's licensing is compatible (GPL).

Comment: Since FPC can be left external, GPl is of no import.

Answer (score 1):

TMS has both a [scripting engine](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudio.asp) and a [scripting IDE](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudiopro.asp) product.